# Python webscraper runs inconsistent in SQL Server Agent

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis, selenium-chromedriver

I have designed a webscraper in python.
This is the code:

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\\DownloadFolder\\"}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
option.add_argument("--start-maximized");
chromedriver = "C:\Script\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=option)


BASE_URl = "https://www.mywebsite.com"
driver.get(BASE_URl)
time.sleep(3)

link2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("mypath").text; 

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(link2)
link.click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

I have created a Job in SQL Server agent that needs to run this webscraper on a specific schedule.
The problem is that the webscraper is sometimes running correctly and sometimes it gives an error.
When it produces an error it first runs infinite.
When it is not able to finish the following error is produced:

> Code: 0xC0029151     Source: Download Execute Process Task
> Description: In Executing "C:\Python\Python392\python.exe"
> "myscript.py" at "C:\script ", The process exit code was "1" while the
> expected was "0".  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned
> DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  19:45:21  Finished: 19:55:28  Elapsed:
> 607.188 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

It is not clear for me what the problem is. If I launch the .py file manually it is always working. In addition, I have embedded the .py file in a SSIS package, this package is the SQL agent using. Also, when I launch the package manually it is also 100% working.

I think that the webscraper after finishing its job the first time, it is not closing all used processes.I tried to add driver.close() before driver.quit() but this is also not working.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Do you actually need to run this in SSIS? Is it doing something that another part of the SSIS package needs to use? Anyway I suggest you look through the SSIS logs to try and find a more detailed error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added headless mode in option which fixed the problem.